# What date formats does the PHP function strtotime() support?

Tags: php, datetime

I really like the PHP function strtotime(), but the [user manual](http://ca.php.net/strtotime) doesn't give a complete description of the supported date formats. It only gives a few examples like "10 September 2000", "+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds", and "next Thursday".

Where can I find a complete description?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find anything official, but I saw [a tutorial](http://www.programmers-corner.com/viewTutorial.php/80) that says strtotime()
uses GNU Date Input Formats. Those are described in detail [in the GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html).

One discrepancy I notice is that "next" doesn't match the 
behaviour described in the GNU manual. Using strtotime(), "next Thursday" will give you the same result as "Thursday", unless today is a Thursday.

If today is a Thursday, then

- strtotime("Thursday") == strtotime("today")
- strtotime("next Thursday") == strtotime("today + 7 days")

If today is not a Thursday, then

- strtotime("Thursday") == strtotime("next Thursday")

I'm using PHP 5.2.6.

**Update:**

I guess the user manual has been updated since I posted this, or else I was blind. It now contains a link to the [Date and Time Formats chapter](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), that includes a section on [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: I remember seeing something that said the same thing, so I'll give you a +1, but this seems a little like you're just trying to earn rep...

Comment: I had to hunt a bit for this, so I posted the question and answer in case others were looking for the same thing. This is an intended use for the site, I think.

Comment: Yes, the FAQ explicitly states that answering your own questions is OK as long as it's in the format of Question<->Answer. If the question is stupid, it will get down voted. Otherwise, this will be useful to others searching for this info in the future.

Comment: you should be able to post a question and answer without getting down votes. just wait a good while before choosing a correct answer, someone might do better then you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can start to trace what it is doing by looking at the following C code:

http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/ext/date/php_date.c

Search for PHP_FUNCTION(strtotime)

Also this is the main regex parsing:

http://cvs.php.net/viewvc.cgi/php-src/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re

Good luck

Comment: Both links are dead.

Comment: Working links: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c & https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re

Answer (score 0):

In my experience strtotime() can accept anything that even remotely looks like a date. The best way to figure out its boundaries are is to create a test script and plug in values and see what does and doesn't work.

```
$input = "Apr 10th";
print(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input)));
```

Just keep changing the $input variable and observe the results.

Answer (score 0):

Basically anything that [date](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) can create strtotime will parse. With one exception, it does have issues with non-US style formatting. So keep it Month-Day-Year type formatting in place.