# strtotime("next march")

Tags: php, time

Going through a weird problem here.

I am trying to get the date of coming March, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$nextMarch = strtotime("next march");
```

What could be wrong with this tiny little code?

This is a question related to this question:
[Timestamp of nearest valid month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872812/timestamp-of-nearest-valid-month)

Comment: Two questions: (1) What *are* you getting (this is vital in all "unexpected behavior" questions)? (2) What version of PHP?

Comment: (1) I am getting nothing. No error. Nothing but empty result. I guess it's returning a boolean false. (2) PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you'll have to give `strtotime` some other (and/or additional) information.

For instance, the number of the day you want in march :

```
$nextMarch = strtotime("1 march");
var_dump($nextMarch, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $nextMarch));
```

But you'll get march this year :

```
int 1235862000
string '2009-03-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
```

So, to get "next" march, i.e., next year :

```
$nextMarch = strtotime("1 march +1 year");
var_dump($nextMarch, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $nextMarch));
```

And you get :

```
int 1267398000
string '2010-03-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
```

So, maybe you'll have to do some calculation by yourself, to know whether you want this year or the next one. Something like this might do the trick:

```
$nextMarch = strtotime("1 march");
if ($nextMarch < time()) {
  $nextMarch = strtotime("1 march +1 year");
}
var_dump($nextMarch, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $nextMarch));
```

*(I don't really like this idea, but it seems to be working -- even though a simpler solution would definitely be nice...)*

Comment: You would actually need a counter variable for this, right? Something like strtotime("1 march +"+year_counter+" year");

Comment: Slightly simpler:

    $yr = 'this';
    if (time() >= strtotime('March 1st')) {
        $yr = 'next';
    }
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($yr . ' year March 1st'));

Comment: Thank you for that piece of explanation! Sometimes we believe that strtotime is more intelligent.

Answer (score 1):

Using strtotime here seems a bit odd and weird for me.
I'd prefer using [mktime](http://uk.php.net/mktime/) for this.

```
mktime (0,0,0,3,1,date("Y")+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

strtotime() is not that smart. You can only do weekdays with next or last.

Comment: PHP 4.4.0 does yield 1235862000 which is 2009-01-01 in GMT+1 (using localtime is a bit stupid but maybe that's just one obscure PHP option)

Comment: Really? What does "next month" give you? You may be (un)pleasantly surprised.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'date of coming March'? March is a collection of 31 dates (one for each day).

Anyway, [this example of strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#89184) (from the online Manual) uses 'next month', to return "the last day of the current month"

It might be worth a look.

Comment: That example goes a bit overboard. The last day of the month can be gotten with *date('t')*.

Comment: Yes, but it shows, at least, that 'next month' is valid (which wasn't my first impression), and I thought it could be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to do more mangling myself and rely less on strtotime:

```
$thisYear = date("Y");
$nextYear = $thisYear + 1;
$nextMarch = date($yourFormat, strtotime("March 1, $nextYear"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar on another project, here's what did:

```
function getNextMarch($timestamp) {



$fields = array();
$fields['timestamp'] = $timestamp;
$fields['unixtime'] = strtotime($timestamp);
$fields['current_month'] = date("m", $fields['unixtime']);
$fields['end_date_pre'] = new DateTime($fields['timestamp']);

switch ($fields['current_month']) {
    case 4 :
        $return = 11;
        break;
    case 5 :
        $return = 10;
        break;
    case 6 :
        $return = 9;
        break;
    case 7 :
        $return = 8;
        break;
    case 8 :
        $return = 7;
        break;
    case 9 :
        $return = 6;
        break;
    case 10 :
        $return = 5;
        break;
    case 11 :
        $return = 4;
        break;
    case 12 :
        $return = 3;
        break;
    case 1 :
        $return = 2;
        break;
    case 2 :
        $return = 1;
        break;
    case 3 :
        $return = 0;
        break;
}
$fields['str'] = $return . ' months';
if ($return > 1) {
    $fields['str'] = $return . ' month';
}

date_add($fields['end_date_pre'], date_interval_create_from_date_string($fields['str']));
return $fields['end_date_post'] = $fields['end_date_pre']->format('Y-m-d G:i:s');
```

}