# Invalid date value storing in atk4 MVCForm

Tags: atk4

I have created a form using MVCForm and set Model class extended Model_Table. In model class I have a date field.
I tried to edit existing record (using GET and loadData() in model), but date field populating with invalid data for example if I saved 10/01/2012 (M/d/Y) , it populated with 01/10/2012

I have following config for date

```
$config['locale']['time']='H:i:s';
$config['locale']['date']='m/d/Y';
$config['locale']['date_js']='mm/dd/yy';
$config['locale']['datetime']='m/d/Y H:i:s';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out these Github links. Maybe you can find something useful there.

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/92

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/89

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues/90

I was working on custom date, datetime need too, but right now have put this issue on the pause because it have lower priority in my project.

Comment: I have commented line #62 to #65 in set function in  https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Form/Field/DatePicker.php#L51 . Now working as expected. Can you please tell the purpose of commented code?

Comment: I'm not sure these lines are correct. Need to deeper check them then.
_if(!$value)return parent::set($value);_ This sets value using parent (Field_Line) method if value is not. Basically useless row I guess.
_@list($d,$m,$y)=explode('/',$value);_ Tries to extract day, month, year values from $value if it's in format d/m/Y (default format).
_if($y)$value=join('/',array($m,$d,$y));_ If year is set (probably extraction was correct, but it lacks validation), then convert $value to m/d/Y format.
_elseif($m)$value=join('/',array($m,$d));_ Else if month is set then convert $value to m/d format.

Comment: To tell the truth - these lines look very suspicious and probably are not 100% correct. I'll look in date and datetime localization issues later in my project when it'll come to this. Then I'll probably pull some patch for this.
BTW - ATK4 by default (same as jQuery UI) have no support for datetime input widgets. You can only use simple textfields as replacement and no calendar widget.

Comment: With other frameworks such as Symfony they allow user to convert database value into something different as it is stored inside model. Agile Toolkit have no support for that, so y-m-d always used for database support. Fields, on other hand, can change format for presentation purposes and also change it back when it's collected. It's advised to use that inside JavaScript. Also - Look into redefining  https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Form/Field.php#L198. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762389/what-date-formats-does-the-php-function-strtotime-support